# How can I loop through my json data in js to make cards in my html page

Tags: javascript, css, json

```
var data = 
[  
   {  
      "name":"john",
      "description":"im 22",
      "email":"123@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
     "name":"jessie",
     "description":"im 12",
     "email":"1234@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
     "name":"jackson",
     "description":"im 32",
     "email":"1235@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
     "name":"jason",
     "description":"im 27",
     "email":"1236@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

this is my json data Im trying to make the name the card title, the email the sub title, and the description the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to iterate item in the array, 
If you target web you can use Div instead of View and P instead of Text

```
Data.map((item)=>{
   return (
    <View>
        <Text> {item.name} </Text>
        <Text> {item.title} </Text>
        <Text> {item.descreption} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```